# How to fix Node.js Square SDK vs TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, square

I'm using Nest.js with Node version 14.16.0 and Square version 11.0.0
But when I run `npm start`, build I faced about 10 errors like this:

```
node_modules/square/src/models/additionalRecipient.ts:23:14 - error TS2322: Type 'StrictObjectSchema<string, { locationId: ["location_id", Schema<string, string>]; description: ["description", Schema<string, string>]; amountMoney: ["amount_money", Schema<Money, any>]; receivableId: [...]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Schema<AdditionalRecipient, any>'.
The types returned by 'map(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type '{ description?: string; amountMoney?: Money; locationId?: string; receivableId?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AdditionalRecipient'.
Property 'locationId' is optional in type '{ description?: string; amountMoney?: Money; locationId?: string; receivableId?: string; }' but required in type 'AdditionalRecipient'.
```

I tried with all other versions of Node.js Square SDK but nothing works.

Comment: What version of nest are you version? Because I tried it and its working for me.

Did you just installed it or imported the sdk anywhere in the code?

Comment: The problem is square know only works with typescript version <= 3.9.7. But my nestjs project use version 4.1.5 typescript. Need square to be updated with new version of typescript later

Comment: Strange..My typescript version is 4.2.4 and it's working.

Comment: Please try adding this line: "import { CreateOrderRequest } from 'square/src/models/createOrderRequest';". You will the error.

Comment: Ah! yes I got the error now. but I'm not sure why are you import from "square/src/models...."? Why not import from "square"?

import { CreateOrderRequest } from 'square'; <-- Works

Comment: Cool, it's just a suggest from IDE :D. Thanks mate!

Comment: Did it worked then? @ndc_lara